# df human-readable calculation

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I was wonder why there is a difference between the reported size of a filesystem with `df -h` and calculating it manually. for example:

The size according to LVM:

```
 # lvdisplay system/var | grep -i size
 LV Size                4.00 GiB
```

Human Readable:

```
# df -h /var
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-var  4.0G  361M  3.4G  10% /var
```

In KB block size:

```
# df -k /var
Filesystem             1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/system-var   4128448 369480   3549256  10% /var
```

And calculating GB from KB:

```
# perl -E 'say $_/(1024*1024) foreach ( 4128448 , 369480 , 3549256 );'
3.93719482421875
0.352363586425781
3.38483428955078
```

3.93G is a bit too far away from 4G to account for rounding. Whereas 360.8203125 seems close enough to 361 as does 3.38G from 3.4G.

So why is there a discrepancy for the total file system size? If it is rounding, why does it need to when total size should be fixed to 4GB?

Comment: The result will be rounded up to nearest integer, as defined by POSIX.

Comment: @cuonglm - Wouldn't 3.93 round down (or POSIX = ceil )? Also, for 'total size' why do we need to round at all ?

Comment: Yes, `human-readable` isn't POSIX, but POSIX defined that the result of those fields will be rounded up. Read [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/df.html#tag_04_36_10) for more details.

Comment: POSIX states that it's _rounded up to the next higher unit (512 bytes or 1k when `-k` is used) not to the next integer_. It's most likely due to the reserved space (aka root space) which is included in the "total size" column.